# Target ID is not recognized during android create project action

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create android project using `android create project` action with options like below

```
root@123-PC: android create project --name Sample --path .--target android-18 
--package com.mobile.sample --activity Main
```

**Below error shows up!**

```
Error: Argument 'android-18' is not recognized.

       Usage:
       android [global options] create project [action options]
       Global options:
  -h --help       : Help on a specific command.
  -v --verbose    : Verbose mode, shows errors, warnings and all messages.
     --clear-cache: Clear the SDK Manager repository manifest cache.
  -s --silent     : Silent mode, shows errors only.

                         Action "create project":
  Creates a new Android project.
Options:
  -n --name          : Project name.
  -v --gradle-version: Gradle Android plugin version.
  -t --target        : Target ID of the new project. [required]
  -p --path          : The new project's directory. [required]
  -g --gradle        : Use gradle template.
  -k --package       : Android package name for the application. [required]
  -a --activity      : Name of the default Activity that is created.
                       [required]
```

But, when I list the available targets, it shows it. `android-18` is present. Can someone help me understand what's
going in the behind scene?

```
root@123-PC: android list targets
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-15"
     Name: Android 4.0.3
     Type: Platform
     API level: 15
     Revision: 3
     Skins: WXGA800, HVGA, WSVGA, WQVGA400, WVGA854, QVGA, WXGA720, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default)
     ABIs : armeabi-v7a
----------
id: 2 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:15"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 2
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 4.0.3 (API level 15)
     Libraries:
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: WVGA854, WQVGA400, WSVGA, WXGA720, HVGA, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), QVGA, WXGA800
     ABIs : armeabi-v7a
----------
id: 3 or "android-18"
     Name: Android 4.3
     Type: Platform
     API level: 18
     Revision: 2
     Skins: WXGA800, HVGA, WXGA800-7in, WSVGA, WQVGA400, WVGA854, QVGA, WXGA720, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default)
     ABIs : armeabi-v7a
----------
id: 4 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:18"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 2
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 4.3 (API level 18)
     Libraries:
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: WVGA854, WQVGA400, WSVGA, WXGA720, WXGA800-7in, HVGA, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), QVGA, WXGA800
     ABIs : armeabi-v7a
```

What could be the reason? I think i am overlooking something here, which i couldn't find for more than a hour. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.--target

Remove that dot

--target

Answer (score 0):

This should be the right command (btw you should define a path, just to make things as clear as you can):

android create project \
--target 3 \
--name Sample \
--path ./Sampleproject \
--activity Main \
--package com.example.Sample